# Cannot install lmfit, "Command returned non-zero exit status 1"

Tags: python, spyder, lmfit

I'm trying to install the `lmfit` package but I keep getting the same error:

`Command '['C:\\Users\\me\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Spyder\\Python\\python.exe', '-m', 'pip', '--disable-pip-version-check', 'wheel', '--no-deps', '-w', 'C:\\Users\\me\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmpeds77q3s', '--quiet', 'setuptools_scm']' returned non-zero exit status 1.`

I'm working with Spyder, Python version 3.7. I looked online but I can't seem to find a solution that works for me.

EDIT:
So, i opened a command line on Miniconda3, run pip install setuptools_smc and then pip install lmfit this happened:

(base) C:\Users\me>pip install lmfit

Collecting lmfit

Using cached lmfit-1.0.3-py3-none-any.whl

Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=1.4 in c:\programdata\miniconda3\lib\site-packages (from lmfit) (1.7.3)

Requirement already satisfied: asteval>=0.9.22 in c:\programdata\miniconda3\lib\site-packages (from lmfit) (0.9.26)

Requirement already satisfied: uncertainties>=3.0.1 in c:\programdata\miniconda3\lib\site-packages (from lmfit) (3.1.6)

Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.18 in c:\programdata\miniconda3\lib\site-packages (from lmfit) (1.22.1)

Requirement already satisfied: future in c:\programdata\miniconda3\lib\site-packages (from uncertainties>=3.0.1->lmfit) (0.18.2)

Installing collected packages: lmfit

Successfully installed lmfit-1.0.3

after that, I went back to Spyder and simply tried to run import lmfit on a new, clean script. That's what I got:

runfile('C:/Users/me/Desktop/untitled0.py', wdir='C:/Users/me/Desktop')

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\me\Desktop\untitled0.py", line 8, in import lmfit

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lmfit'

feels like I'm back at the starting point. i forgot to mention that; but I'm running on Windows.

P.s.: i don't think I'm using any virtual environment, just Miniconda3 and Spyder

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Spyder passes the `--quiet` argument to `pip`, which suppresses the actual error output. Open a command line and install `lmfit` manually with `pip`. If there's some output, please copy the complete output into your question. Do you use a virtual enviroment (venv)?

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Since it seems you're using our Windows installer and also installed Miniconda, please read [our FAQ](https://docs.spyder-ide.org/5/faq.html#using-packages-installer) to learn how to connect them.

Answer (score 0):

installing `lmfit` with `pip` works fine at least on macOS, but admittedly I have never tried on Windows... To me it seems that it cannot find `setuptools_scm` even though we do [declare it as a dependency](https://github.com/lmfit/lmfit-py/blob/9f9af6f36c0928767ea8b004ea8cb5a16aba6b04/setup.py#L31).

Try installing that package first (`pip install setuptools_scm`) and then install `lmfit` (`pip install lmfit`) again. I don't see how that would make a difference, but it's worth a try! Also, please do provide the *exact* command you use to install `lmfit`.